# How to test login functionality via J meter where some system generated value is also seen in along with username and password?

Tags: jmeter

Like after recording login action when request is viewed then seeing sysparm_ck also along with login and password. When this scrip is run then due to sysparm_ck parameter login is not getting performed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should design your test scenario as follows:

- Open Login Page (normally HTTP GET Request)

  - Extract `sysparm_ck` from the response and save it into a [JMeter Variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) with a [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
- Perform Login (normally HTTP POST Request) providing credentials and the JMeter Variable holding `sysparm_ck` value

The whole process is known as [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-load-testing-scenarios-jmeter-part-1-correlations) and depending on the "Open Login Page" response nature you have the following PostProcessors choices:

1. [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) - probably the most commonly used one
2. [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor) - for HTML
3. [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) - for XML, XHTML and HTML
4. [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) - for JSON